# {Javascript} How to return Json when calling POST xmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, django

I tried to use xmlHttpRequest POST to upload file in Meteor project. With Django REST framework 2.3.14.

I used:

```
var file = $('#control_import_file')[0].files[0];
var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
    if (e.target.status == 200) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(e.target.response);
        if (resp.status == 'success') {
            alert("success");
        } else {
            alert("fail");
        }
    }
};
xmlHttpRequest.onload = function () {};

xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "http://mydemosite.net/orders/import-coupon/25/", true);

if (window.FormData) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("datafile", file);
    xmlHttpRequest.send(formData);
}
```

In Chrome, it returns:

> Event {isTrusted: true, type: "readystatechange", target:
>   XMLHttpRequest, currentTarget: XMLHttpRequest, eventPhase: 2…}

So I can easyly get Json string: target.response object:

> ""{"status": "error", "data": {"error_data": ["test123"],
>   "error_code": 0, "error_msg": "Check failed"}, "error_data":
>   ["test123"], "error_code": 0, "error_msg": "Check failed"}"

JSON.parse(e.target.response); --> get sth I want.

However in Firefox: it returns all that json string above in HTML format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE"...</html>
```

Anyone can help me how to handle error response in Firefox? Or Is there any way to get response in all browsers?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery?

Comment: Relevant http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif - not a jab at you @DanielRoseman, just what I think whenever anyone suggests it now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framwork checks the "Accept" header to define if he must return HTML, JSON, CSV or any other format that he can render (cf: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/)

since you are manually using XMLHttpRequest, try adding the accept header with [setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader). Something like:

```
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
```

check in your console that you are passing the correct headers on Chrome and Firefox

Hope this helps

Comment: Fantastic! Many thanks! I tried to setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html"); Now I know why it doesnt work =))))